# Kubernetes pod scheduling failed with 1 node(s) didn't satisfy existing pods anti-affinity rules

Tags: kubernetes

Our K8S setup runs on baremetal with 1 master-node and 1 worker-node and we already deployed few pods on it

We added a new worker-node

```
NAME              STATUS   ROLES                  AGE   VERSION
master-node       Ready    control-plane,master   27d   v1.20.2
worker-node-new   Ready    <none>                 20h   v1.20.2
worker-node-2     Ready    worker                 27d   v1.20.0
```

and wanted to **evenly distribute** some of the pods to both the worker nodes

PodAffinity snippet is provided below

```
 affinity:
   podAntiAffinity:
      preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
      - weight: 100
        podAffinityTerm:
          labelSelector:
            matchExpressions:
            - key: app                      
              operator: In
              values:
              - ursip-siphttp
          topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
```

but pod remains in state **Pending**

**Pod Status**

```
NAME                         READY    STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
http-574f66f744-2xckb         0/1     Pending             0          15m
http-7867465c7d-nn8zw         1/1     Running             0          84m
```

**Error Message (from Pending Pod)**

```
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age                From               Message
  ----     ------            ----               ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  58s (x2 over 58s)  default-scheduler  0/3 nodes are available: 1 node(s) didn't match pod affinity/anti-affinity, 1 node(s) didn't satisfy existing pods anti-affinity rules, 2 node(s) had volume node affinity conflict.
```

I google'd a lot but unfortunately I am unable to fix this

Comment: Please post your deployment.  And indicate on which node the pod starts. kubectl get po -n thenamespace -o wide. The pod antiaffinity doesnt allow to start a new instance on a node where a pod is already running with the same labels. Most probably on the other nodes it cant start because of the volumes. Are you using nfs or localStorage class?

Comment: @Ralle  You spotted the issue.  As you mentioned there were localStorage used which I had to modify accordingly and now it works fine

Comment: Since your issue is resolved can you post the solution you have followed for greater visibility of the community .